Spring Security требует авторизацию
При попытке добавить пользователя, отпраляя post запрос по пути "/register/user", всё равно требует авторизации. Хотя, учитывая конфиг, не должно. Думал, что дело в csrf, однако отключение не решило проблему. В чём может быть дело?
package org.example.sectest;

 import org.example.sectest.model.MyUserDetailService;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
 import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
 import    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig {

@Autowired
MyUserDetailService myUserDetailService;


@Bean
public DefaultSecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(registry->{
        registry.requestMatchers("/home","/register/user").permitAll();
        registry.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
        registry.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER");
        registry.anyRequest().authenticated();
    })
            .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return myUserDetailService;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authConfigProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}


Есть вероятность, что /register/user выкидывает исключение и редиректит ответ на error страницу. Попробуйте добавить так registry.requestMatchers("/home", "/register/user", "error").permitAll();
